# C# - TreeView construction

Tags: c#, treeview, menu, contextmenu

I am trying to construct a TreeView from a Menu. My Code is like this:

```
public class MenuExtractionUtility
    {
        public TreeView MenuTraverse(MainMenu mainMenu)
        {
            TreeView treeView = new TreeView();

            TreeNode mainNode = new TreeNode();

            foreach (MenuItem mi in mainMenu.MenuItems)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(mi.Text);

                mainNode.Text = mi.Text;

                TreeNode tn = MenuItemTraverse(mi);

                mainNode.Nodes.Add(tn);
            }

            treeView.Nodes.Add(mainNode);

            return treeView;
        }

        private TreeNode MenuItemTraverse(MenuItem menuItem)
        {
            TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode();

            foreach(MenuItem mi in menuItem.MenuItems)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(mi.Text);

                treeNode.Text = mi.Text;

                TreeNode tr = MenuItemTraverse(mi);

                if (tr!=null && tr.Text != "")
                {
                    treeNode.Nodes.Add(tr);
                }
            }

            return treeNode;
        }
    }
```

But this is not working.

What can be the problem?

Comment: WTF in down voting? What this people think of them by voting down?

Comment: My guess is that the downvote came from the question largely consisting of a code listing without a detailed information about in what way it does not work. But I personally dislike downvoting without giving reasons; it's hard to correct shortcomings in a post if there is not indication what the shortcoming is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two problems in the methods. Let's start with the `MenuItemTraverse` method. You get a `MenuItem` as input. You declare a `TreeNode` variable, and assign a new `TreeNode` instance to it. Then you loop over the menu item's sub items. For each iteration you assign the text from the sub item to the `TreeNode` (I would assume that you would want the text of the incoming menu item on this `TreeNode`). To get the intended behaviour you should remove this line from the loop:

```
treeNode.Text = mi.Text;
```

...and add this line before the loop:

```
treeNode.Text = menuItem.Text;
```

It looks like you have the exact same problem in the `MenuTraverse` method, so do the same change there. I think that would solve it for you (didn't test the code yet; might have missed something).

**Update**

I gave it a bit of though, since I felt that the code could probably be simplified a bit, and this is what I came up with. Instead of having two different methods for `MainMenu` and `MenuItem` input, this one encapsulates the process into one single method. Also, it takes a `TreeNodeCollection`, which means that you can have the method inject the menu structure into an already existing (and populated) `TreeView` control, at any level in the tree.

```
public class MenuExtractionUtility
{
    public static void MenuItemTraverse(TreeNodeCollection parentCollection, Menu.MenuItemCollection menuItems)
    {
        foreach (MenuItem mi in menuItems)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(mi.Text);
            TreeNode menuItemNode = parentCollection.Add(mi.Text);
            if (mi.MenuItems.Count > 0)
            {
                MenuItemTraverse(menuItemNode.Nodes, mi.MenuItems);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
MenuExtractionUtility.MenuItemTraverse(treeView1.Nodes, mainMenu1.MenuItems);
```

This code was just quickly put together, so you may want to "stabilize" it a bit by adding null checks and similar.

Comment: Sorry I was busy testing your code. Excellent job @Fredrik!

Meanwhile I have come up with my own corrections buddy!

Answer (score 0):

here it is...

```
public class MenuExtractionUtility
    {
        public void MenuTraverse(MainMenu mainMenu, TreeView treeView)
        {
            TreeNode ultimateMainNode = new TreeNode();
            ultimateMainNode.Text = "Root";

            TreeNode mainNode = null;

            foreach (MenuItem mi in mainMenu.MenuItems)
            {
                if (mi != null && mi.Text != "")
                {
                    mainNode = null;

                    if (mi.MenuItems.Count <= 0)
                    {
                        mainNode = new TreeNode();
                        mainNode.Text = mi.Text;
                    }
                    else if (mi.MenuItems.Count > 0)
                    {
                        mainNode = MenuItemTraverse(mi);
                    }

                    ultimateMainNode.Nodes.Add(mainNode);
                }
            }

            treeView.Nodes.Add(ultimateMainNode);
        }

        private TreeNode MenuItemTraverse(MenuItem menuItem)
        {
            TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(menuItem.Text+",");
            treeNode.Text = menuItem.Text;

            foreach (MenuItem mi in menuItem.MenuItems)
            {
                if (mi != null && mi.Text != "")
                {
                    TreeNode tr = MenuItemTraverse(mi);

                    if (tr != null && tr.Text != "")
                    {
                        treeNode.Nodes.Add(tr);
                    }
                }
            }

            return treeNode;
        }
```